# Sessions folder is always empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, upload, logout

I'm facing a strange issue which I cannot still figured out. When I logged in Magento admin panel and try to upload an image to a static block, Magento auto log-outs. Actually whenever I try to upload anything in admin panel it automatically log-outs. Var and it's inner folders have permission 775.

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: try to remove cache from var/cache

Comment: have you install any module?

Comment: Not installed any module. I tried it

Comment: Rename Var to something else, and check if var is created itself with specific permissions, or  create you own var folder with 777 permissions and same to subfolders

Answer (score 3):

This is normally a permission issue, go to your magento root folder and do chmod -R 777 var

Comment: It is not secure to give full permission (777) to all the folders in server. Isn't it enough 775?

Answer (score 1):

check your config urls, mainly cookie domain and session timeout. Auto logout is often connected to this.

In System => Configuration => Web => Session Cookie Management

Cookie Lifetime -> this field CAN'T be empty

Cookie Domain -> must match your domain

Comment: Can you give more details about what the OP should check?

Comment: @Marius edited answer

Comment: That's better..

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have configured your Magento to store session in database instead of the var folder. Check the `session_save` setting in app/etc/local.xml. More information: http://www.aip.im/2012/07/configure-magento-to-store-session-data-in-the-database/